# Javascript variable scope issue - selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Im relatively new to javascript and am trying to create a function that will contain some reusable code for selenium web driver so i can reuse it across multiple tests.

it is not working and i think it may be some scoping issue that i do not understand.

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
require('chromedriver');
var should = require('chai').should();

const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

describe ("test suite", function() {

    it("can open", async function() {
        
        // This does not work
        //openUrl('https//www.google.co.uk/');

        // This does work
        await driver.get('https//www.google.co.uk/');

        var titletext = await driver.getTitle();
        titletext.should.eq('Google');
        await driver.quit();

    });
});


async function openUrl(urlString) {
    // This opens the browser but the address bar contains: data:,
    await driver.get(urlString);
}
```

If i

expected result
I expect that the browser window would open and 'https//www.google.co.uk/' would open

Actual Result
The browser window opens but the address bar contains the test: data:,

Answer (score 0):

1. I would start by using the [selenium sample](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html) and without a unit test framework.
2. There are (at least) two problems in this code:

- The function `build` returns a promise, so you should use `const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();` in the async function
- The url you are using is not valid. Try using "http://www.google.com/ncr"